# how to convert vb code to c# code in getparentpath field?

Tags: c#

```
        filepath2 = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetParentPath(filepath)
```

this is my code what should I do to convert to c#? what should I have to add to my library or references?
 I change it to c# but .GetPatrentPath doesn't exist in c#, can anybody help me?

Comment: You need to learn about `System. IO` in C#

Answer (score 0):

> This is my code what should I do to convert to c#?

1. Add `System.IO` library to your code.
2. Use [`Directory.GetParent(string path)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getparent?view=netframework-4.8) method to get parent directory path

Like,

```
using System.IO; 
...
string parentPath = Directory.GetParent(filepath);
```